# url parsing(webparsing) in python

Tags: python, parsing, url-parsing

On every monday, I need to parse last weeks(5 days) "USD RATES 1100". So, for that I need to select date for every day of last week and "USD RATES 1100" from series drop down. I need only 1 year tenor rate. So final answer should have 5 values of 1 year tenor of "USD RATES 1100".

https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\vick\Desktop\python_1\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180")
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

Comment: Can you show us any code you've tried?

Comment: To get xpath in chrome, all you have to do is inspect, right click the element, select copy, and then by xpath

Comment: I have return the code(added in question) which is very basic. I am not getting anything in xpath by which I can parse all the required values

Comment: //*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span

Comment: Try this xpath. Then click

Comment: I have written this:                                       
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='USD RATES 1100']/a/span"). I am getting this error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='USD RATES 1100']/a/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: Try  
`//*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span` xpath instead

Comment: And see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\vick\Desktop\python_1\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180")
try:
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
except:
  pass

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/div/ul/li[5]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').send_keys("27-Jul-2017") #or whatever date
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectForm"]/input').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)/2;")
print ( driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML') )
```

This will select `USD RATES 1100`, enter a date, and submit. You can loop this process to enter more dates.

Comment: Sir, thankyou very much for the answer. But for me, instead of "USD RATS 1100" it is still giving "EUR RATES 110"

Comment: Found the bug, will fix

Comment: Sir,Thank you very much. I am finding this difficult to solve. I am still have  a doubt, after opening of the page, when I am doing inspect element, still I am not able to find "usd rate 1100" value correspoding to "1 year". Inspect element is showing the same original page. Again thank you very much for answering my questions.

Comment: The XPATH of for the one year number is `//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]`

Comment: It is giving me this error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: The reason is that you need to scroll down with javascript. There is the `execute_script` function to do that

Comment: Edited the answer for that

Comment: I was trying the last part from last 2 days and I didn;'t get it. So, I asked another question in stackoverflow regarding that. One of the person help, we need to add "time.sleep(5) " after execute_script line. After adding that line, code ran perfectly fine. After understanding your code, I have parsed 3 more website including linkedin. Thank you for all the help. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\vick\Desktop\python_1\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180")
try:
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/
   div[2]/button').click()
except:
      pass

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/div/ul/li[5]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').send_keys("27-Jul-
2017") #or whatever date
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectForm"]/input').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)/2;")
time.sleep(4)
print ( (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-
content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML')).
strip() )
```